# Get user from DB and put attribiutes in label

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, spring-webflux

I have simple Vaadin GUI which I would like connect with my Rest API on localhost:8080:

```
@Route("hello")
public class EmployeeGui extends VerticalLayout {

    private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");

    public EmployeeGui() {
        TextField textEmployee = new TextField("Give id of user");
        Button buttonOK = new Button("OK");
        Label label = new Label();

        buttonOK.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            this.webClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("/employee/{id}")
                            .build(textEmployee.getValue()))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(EmployeeTo.class)
                            .subscribe(emp -> {
                                   label.setText(emp.getName());
                                });
                            });

        add(textEmployee,buttonOK, label);
    }
}
```

On localhost:8080 works my backend application which give me REST API to retrive some data from DB.

In text field we can put id of user and then click OK-button. After that in label we set name of user. Unfortunately I got exception (in line `label.setText(emp.getName());`):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the session.

I understood it, but how can I omit this problem? How can I put user Id and then return User attributes to label after OK button was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

When you react to the request from your API, the "request" from Vaadin is
already done.  If you want to make that work you would have to enable `@Push`
(so Vaadin can send changes from the server when they happen) and make sure you
access the UI in a safe way (see ["Asynchronous Updates" in the
docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html) for
details).

Or you actually don't need that to be async and
use the web client in a blocking way (so the client blocks and the label change
happens inside the "request" triggered by the button.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the question is using `@Push` ([Doc 1](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html), [Doc 2](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html)) to update the ui when the main request has already been responded to (because your `webClient.get()` is asynchronous). The fix to your problem looks like this:

```
@Push
@Route("hello")
public class EmployeeGui extends VerticalLayout {

    private UI ui;
    private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");

    public EmployeeGui() {
        TextField textEmployee = new TextField("Give id of user");
        Button buttonOK = new Button("OK");
        Label label = new Label();

        // keep instance of UI in a field,
        // and update it whenever the EmployeeGui is (re-)attached to the page
        // (important when using @PreserveOnRefresh or RouterLayout)
        addAttachListener(event -> {
            this.ui = event.getUI();
        });

        buttonOK.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            this.webClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("/employee/{id}")
                            .build(textEmployee.getValue()))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(EmployeeTo.class)
                            .subscribe(emp -> {
                                   // use ui.access to obtain lock on UI, perform updates within
                                   getUI().access(() -> label.setText(emp.getName()));
                                });
                            });

        add(textEmployee,buttonOK, label);
    }

    private UI getUI(){
        return this.ui;
    }
}
```

But *depending on what you want to do* with your application, I can recommend using [Spring Security](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security) to make the user Log in, then you have easy and direct access to the current username.